# Control what can connect to systemd's rpcbind/portmap service (port 111)

Tags: linux, security, systemd

systemd on my box is listening to port 111 for the [rpcbind/portmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmap) service.  Lets say I wanted to allow some other computers to connect to it, but not all. Is there any way besides a firewall to control what can connect to this service?  Poking around I see that the `rpcbind` binary is linked against the [TCP Wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrapper) `tcp_wrappers-libs` library, meaning it can use [`/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-TCP_Wrappers_and_xinetd-TCP_Wrappers_Configuration_Files.html).  However, I don't know if systemd immediately hands connections to port 111 over to the rpcbind binary, or if it does some of its own processing first.

My system is a standard desktop install of Fedora 25.

Comment: generally it would have been useful to gesture towards how you ended up with systemd listening on port 111.  E.g. if you didn't knowingly do anything relating to it, what distribution and version you installed; that's always nice information to have.  If you did: why did you want rpcbind enabled.  It's also not clear whether you wanted to allow connections but only for localhost: for many services that's easier or more secure than the category of controls which `hosts.allow` falls under.

Comment: amusingly it looks like there was code for TCP Wrappers in systemd, in which case it _would_ have been doing some of it's own processing first.  I can't find it referenced in current versions though.  There was a directive  `TCPWrapName=`.